# Adding 280 color values to custom colors values in scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-bar

When filling a stacked bar chart, as in the following example, does scale_fill_manual values have a limit as to the length they allow? I am trying to fill 280 different color values to 280 different car_makes and they are not being read appropriately into the graph.

```
bp_car <- ggplot(df_car, aes(x = car_make, y = proportion, fill = car_make)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white", "black", "silver"))
```

Is there another method for filling in the colors that might work for me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my experience, one reaches the limit of how many different colours the human eye can distinguish *way* before any limit on `scale_fill_manual`'s part...

Comment: See also https://guides.library.duke.edu/datavis/topten

Comment: What exactly does the "not appropriately" mean?  Consider gradient fills.  But it depends on what do you want to achieve.